# WPF sub menuitems closes before mouse reach them

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, taskbar

A very few people have this problem that they cannot react the sub menuitems because it closes too fast before the mouse can reach the sub menu. Added a GIF at the bottom. We cannot reproduce this behaviour and it seems to affect very few people.
[image]

We use Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarIcon to display the menu. Any ideas would be appreciated. Here is a snippet of the code where I illustrated only 1 menu item but the others follow the same logic:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:tb="http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FreedomPlatform"
                    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:FreedomPlatform.Converters">
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    <converters:InverseBooleanConverter x:Key="InverseBooleanConverter" />
    <converters:InverseAndBooleanConverter x:Key="InverseAndBooleanConverter" />
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="FreedomTrayMenu" AutomationProperties.Name="Freedom">
        
        <MenuItem Header="Options">
            <MenuItem Header="Run on Startup" StaysOpenOnClick="True" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding RunOnStartup}" IsEnabled="{Binding RunOnStartupModificationEnabled}" />
            
        </MenuItem>
        <Separator />
    </ContextMenu>
    
    <tb:TaskbarIcon x:Key="FreedomNotifyIcon"
                    IconSource="{Binding StatusIconPath}"
                    ContextMenu="{StaticResource FreedomTrayMenu}" MenuActivation="LeftOrRightClick" KeyUp="{Binding OnKeyUp}">
        
        <!-- Self-assign a data context (could also be done programmatically) -->
        <tb:TaskbarIcon.DataContext>
            <local:StatusViewModel />
        </tb:TaskbarIcon.DataContext>
    </tb:TaskbarIcon>
    
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: The real Win32 HMENU does not do this.

Comment: You mean there is a problem with the package that we use?

Comment: The behavior in .NET 6 is different in that the top-level `MenuItem` is not immediately deselected when the mouse leaves but after a slight delay, which allows enough time for the sub-menu to remain open until the mouse enters it.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting OnMouseLeave on the parent MenuItem like this

```xml
<ResourceDictionary ... 
    x:Class="ContextMenuHandler">
    <!--...-->
    <MenuItem Header="Options" MouseLeave="OnMouseLeave">
        <!--...-->
    </MenuItem>
    <!--...-->
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then also add a class called ContextMenuHandler.cs

```cs
    public partial class ContextMenuHandler : ResourceDictionary
    {
        public void OnMouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're bond to use Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarIcon, talk with the guy that wrote the TaskBarIcon ;)

If NOT, I suggest to you to use `System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon` and write some C# code, [here a question with a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674761/can-i-use-notifyicon-in-wpf), see the answer, accepted , by [Jesper Jensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/958701/jesper-jensen).

Mind that the Icon in tray is owned by Windows and WPF is only a different UI of a Windows exe, that mind that you can use, by C# code, a NotifyIcon or whatever you want from Windows.

NotifyIcon expose methods to handle Click on Balloon, on Icon, Mouse events, etc.