# Why this code snippet doesn't work in my VS2012

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2012

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ///托盘图标呈现；
        System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon ni = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
        ni.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("Main.ico");
        ni.Visible = true;
        ni.DoubleClick +=
            delegate(object sender, EventArgs args)
            {
                this.Show();
                this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            };

    }


   //窗口状态变化事件
    protected override void OnStateChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
            this.Hide();  //即，如果收到“窗口最小化”命令，则窗口隐藏。

        base.OnStateChanged(e); //如果不是，不做处理（准确的说，是根据参数e做调整）
    }


}
```

I am trying to realize my App MainWindow minimize to traypanel.And I found this code snippet.But it doesn't work in my VS2012.

source:([Easiest way to have a program minimize itself to the system tray using .NET 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230579/easiest-way-to-have-a-program-minimize-itself-to-the-system-tray-using-net-4))

I guess it's because I didn't have an icon file in the Project.So, I selected an icon file(.ico) and paste it to my project.Also ,it doesn't work.

**[Problem Resolved,Thank You All]**
I should paste icon file to the file folder where .exe file was generated.  囧~~

Comment: what do you mean 'doesn't work'?

Comment: If your problem is solved, you should answer your own question and mark that answer as correct.

Comment: OK,I know,thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm lucky to find the resolving method :  paste icon file to the file folder where .exe file was generated,instead of paste it to the project folder in VS.

I don't know why ,but it really works.