# Thread.cs not found when trying to minimize window to system tray

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, system-tray

I am trying to create an wpf app and I want to minimize it to system tray,
I followd [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230579/easiest-way-to-have-a-program-minimize-itself-to-the-system-tray-using-net-4) question and created the following window

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon ni = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
            ni.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("Main.ico");
            ni.Visible = true;
            ni.DoubleClick +=
                delegate (object sender, EventArgs arg)
                {
                    this.Show();
                    this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                };

        }

        protected override void OnStateChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (WindowState == System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized)
                this.Hide();

            base.OnStateChanged(e);
        }
    }
```

however when I tried to run it visual studio opened a window saying "Thread.cs not found"

[image: here is a screen shot]

The exception says "The invocation of the constructor on type 'WpfApplication1.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception ' Line number '6' and line position '9'."

I tried to Enable "just my code" but then the app enter a break mode.
Any idea what is the problem here? Is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: Ignore the error in the background (thread.cs) and focus on the error in the foreground. That is the thing you need to fix.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40320258/34092 .

Comment: I've tried that already.

Comment: Your XAML has an issue at line number 6, column 9.

Comment: add `bool ok = File.Exists("Main.Ico");` on top of the cor and put a breakpoint on it.