# Does WPF have any method to apply a badge to an app icon?

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF app which I'd like to add a badge to its icon under certain conditions - does WPF have a way to do this natively, or should I just replace the icon with a different icon (one to which I've added the badge in an image editor) temporarily when I want the badge to appear?

Comment: I think that you can replace the App icon at runtime. You can also make a NotifyIcon that appears on SysTray https://stackoverflow.com/q/10230579/194717

Comment: Yeah, I already have a tray icon - would like to put a badge over that and over the main app icon.

Answer (score 1):

WPF does not have a built-in method to overlay the icon with a badge, however the method to do it with, `SetOverlayIcon()`, is available in [Windows API Code Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft-WindowsAPICodePack-Core/); take a look at [TaskbarManager.cs](https://github.com/aybe/Windows-API-Code-Pack-1.1/blob/master/source/WindowsAPICodePack/Shell/Taskbar/TaskbarManager.cs). One way to invoke the method in C# would be like:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Taskbar.TaskbarManager.Instance.SetOverlayIcon(myHandle, myIcon, String.Empty);
```